# Installshield Installer MSI Error : Could not load assembly by name "abcd", Version : 6.0.0.0

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installshield, managed

In an Basic MSI project , a function needs to be called from a Managed DLL (C# built in .NET core 6.0). This DLL is added as Support file in MSI. When the MSI is invoked and the custom action is called the path to the managed dll is resolved . But fails with error "Could not load assembly by name Dependent.dll , Version : 6.0.0.0" . How to resolve this issue.?  The custom dll requires some other dll of .net core version to be loaded and used properly. How to add the dependent dll in MSI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add reference of each dependent dll in ISClrWrap table. e.g.

[image]